Using python gooey, is there a way to exit the GUI if run completed successfully
Trying to build a tool that will provide a simple status and log visibility for users, mainly in the case that there is an error or slow processing.  Gooey provides all of the functionality I need, but I'd like the GUI window to close automatically if the script runs successfully.
I can't seem to find a call or user argument to trigger this automatically.

did you try to run exit() or sys.exit() ? The only problem is to detect if  script runs successfully. Usually programs send exit code 0 when it was successful

I've tried sys.exit().  Looks like this is part of the functionality in Gooey which allows you to 'rerun' your script.
